# Random shapes background generator

Tags: javascript, web, animation, random

I'm looking for some kind of random line generator. I would like to be able to generate such pattern like this one

[image: Line pattern]

Also what would be the best approach in case of making animated background of mowing cubes so its lightweight for website. Should I use video for that or maybe some library like Three.js

[image: Moving cubes]

Comment: Hi, have you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Answer (score 0):

Search for "CodePen maze generator", or something to this effect:

https://codepen.io/GabbeV/pen/viAec

```
var directions = [[1,0],[-1,0],[0,1],[0,-1]], alternatives = []
for(var i=0;i<directions.length;i++){
if(map[(directions[i][1]+y)*2]!=undefined&&
   map[(directions[i][1]+y)*2][(directions[i][0]+x)*2]===false){
  alternatives.push(directions[i])
}
}
```

The random line code pattern is not unique to Three.js, so you may find more plentiful resources elsewhere. A more general context will provide examples with max-lines, intersects, symmetry, etc. Three.js can render animated SVG, textures, extruded paths, points and more... once you handle the underlying logic.

The cubes could be an InstancedMesh with, for example, the y-axis animated like Math.sin(timestamp). Or there's a good example of node material by Don McCurdy. He has more than 100 reputation.